# Prove that if 'a', then 'b' if and only if 'c'

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say we have a question

> Prove that if 'a', then 'b' if and only if 'c'.

How can we interpret this statement using symbols?

Is it a -> b <-> c? Or (a -> b) <-> c? Or b <-> (a ∧ c)? Or is it something else?

Comment: Is this the whole context of the question? If a,b,and c are specific math statements, then perhaps we can offer more insights about a possible interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without making the initial statement clearer, it can mean either one of these two **non-equivalent** statements:

$$A \implies (B \iff C)$$
$$(A \implies B) \iff C$$

The comma after `if A` and more importantly the lack of a comma before `if and only if` makes me believe that whoever wrote the statement probably meant the first case. But as I said, it is not perfectly clear. I realise that it is hard to express it clearly and succinctly with words only. I would explicitly write the expression with parentheses to leave any ambiguity out.

Comment: In words, the first one can be expressed as "Assume $A$. Then $B$ if and only if $C$." The best thing to do with complicated statements is to break them down into simpler ones. For the second one, I would write: "the two following statement are equivalents: 1) if $A$, then $B$" 2) $C$". That does not totally satisfy me though. Maybe someone can come up with something better.

Comment: @Taladris, thanks. Your idea of breaking it down in sentences is good, but it gets a little cumbersome. The first case for example is tricker that what you describe  because we have to start with "Prove that". We could use your idea of breaking it down into sentences and get: Prove that that the first sentence implies the second: 1) A, 2) B if and only if C. I would still prefer to write it with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

a->(b<->c)

or in words, a implies b implies c and c implies b

Comment: if b implies c and c implies b then presumably b and c are equivalent. So a-> (b ≡ c)

Comment: How can you exclude that the statement means $(A \implies B) \iff C$? Also note that the "equivalent" statement you wrote below, is itself unclear/ambiguous. It requires parentheses to disambiguate.  For example, $(A \implies B) \implies C$ is different from $A \implies (B \implies C)$

Comment: I think that in general the comma makes it clear. I can see the potential ambiguity, but a plain reading with the comma clears it up for me. Stylistically, it would be better to clear it up!

Comment: I am also **guessing** that they mean the first case, but it is not clear. A comma would be put after the `if` anyway (according to some english guides, for example here: https://www.constant-content.com/content-writing-service/2007/12/if-then-statements-require-commas/). Perhaps the more telling sign is the absence of a comma before `if and only if`. But again it is not crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

$a\implies (b\iff c)\\
\equiv\neg a  \lor(b\implies c \land c\implies b)\\
\equiv (\neg a\lor b \implies c) \land (\neg a \lor c\implies b)\\
\equiv(\neg a \lor (\neg b \lor c)) \land (\neg a \lor (\neg c \lor b))\\
\equiv (\neg(a\land b)\lor c) \land (\neg (a \land c) \lor b)\\
\equiv ((a\land b)\implies c) \land ((a \land c)\implies b)$

So in conclusion, it is equivalent to prove that
(i) (a and b) implies c; and
(ii) (a and c) implies b

Comment: You are not replying to the OP's question. You assume that the statement means $A \implies (B \iff C)$ and then derive some other equivalent expression. The OP explicitly asks which of several interpretations is correct. Only the first two are valid interpretations imo, and they are **not** equivalent. You can check their truth tables at https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/.